# AlarmManager срабатывает только один раз (при старте)

Tags: android-service, android, java, broadcast-receiver

Здравствуйте!
Нужно чтобы приложение ,через установленый интервал, отправляло запрос.
Использую `AlarmManager`, т.к. нет привязки ко времени, важен интервал.
Код `AlarmEvent`'a срабатывает только один раз, и не выполняется через интервал.

LogCat

```
05-22 11:16:05.507    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/MY﹕ onCreate MyApp_ from Singleton
    05-22 11:16:05.507    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/MY﹕ MySingleton::InitInstance()
    05-22 11:16:05.507    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/MY_TAG﹕ MySingleton::MySingleton()
    05-22 11:16:05.651    1527-1527/com.example.projectx W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-22 11:16:05.655    1527-1527/com.example.projectx E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
    05-22 11:16:05.671    1527-1527/com.example.projectx E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
    05-22 11:16:08.103    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/MY_TAG﹕ Check GUID
    05-22 11:16:08.171    1527-1527/com.example.projectx W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-22 11:16:08.211    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/Alarm﹕ Start Service (Location)
    05-22 11:16:08.211    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/Alarm﹕ setAlarm
    05-22 11:16:08.211    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/Alarm﹕ set Alarm.class
    05-22 11:16:08.219    1527-1543/com.example.projectx I/Alarm﹕ ALARM_EVENT
    05-22 11:16:08.295    1527-1527/com.example.projectx W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-22 11:16:08.299    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/GPS﹕ from gps
    05-22 11:16:08.311    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/GPS Enabled﹕ GPS Enabled
    05-22 11:16:08.315    1527-1527/com.example.projectx I/LocationService﹕ служба создана
```

Мой код:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {}
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.mContext = this; 
        getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    public static boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
        Log.i("LocationService ", " is running");
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (LocationService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static String ALARM_EVENT() {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i=0;i<=0;i++) {
// тут будет ALARM_EVENT ( запрос к серверу)
                        Log.i("Alarm", "ALARM_EVENT");
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            return null;
        }

        public static final int ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC = 3;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("Alarm", "Alarm received: " + intent.getAction());

            if (!isRunning(context)) {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.Alarm.class));
            } else {
                Log.i("Alarm", "don't start service: already running...");
            }
        }

        public static void setAlarm(Context context) throws IOException {
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ALARM_EVENT()), 0);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC, pi);
            Log.i("Alarm", "setAlarm");
        }

        public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) throws IOException {
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ALARM_EVENT()), 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Из MainActivity вызываю это все таким образом:

```
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startService(new Intent(UserStartActivity.this, LocationService.class));
        Log.i("Alarm","Start Service (Location)");

        try {
        LocationService.Alarm.setAlarm(this);
        Log.i("Alarm","set Alarm.class");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такое решение проблемы:

```
   //Вызываю в UserActivity в методет onCreate
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.Alarm.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,3);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,30*1000,alarmIntent);
```